# The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, portable-class-library

When compiling, I get this error

`The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found.`

If I comment it out, I get

`The <TargetFrameworkIdentifier> for a portable project must be .NETPortable.`

Have any ideas what this is? Where its supposed to go?

Also, oddly the Portable directory in the first error does not even exist on my hard drive anywhere.
Does anyone know how to get it put back? This is on my main PC too...

It occurs with any version of VS (13 and 15) and I have even uninstalled and re-installed VS.

VS Installation logs also indicated that it could not find the Portable class to update it and then failed to update it. This I thought was directly related to the Portable directory missing. Is there another reason for this. I'll try and get the installer logs with the failure.

After looking at the log file it appears I have registry issue.

`Set_Warning: PkgDef encountered data collision in section &apos;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\NewProjectTemplates\TemplateDirs\{fe426dcb-ff5c-44a9-b84d-24cf031ba095}\/1&apos; for value &apos;&apos;  Source="VisualStudio"`

Thanks

Comment: You need to have VS 2013 Update 2, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I had VS 2013 Update 4 and then added VS 2015. It would be redundant for VS to require VS Update 2 in order to get that... However, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Ok. The updates are cumulative, so Update 4 includes whatever features were in Update 2.

Comment: Yes, and it wasn't working... Any other ideas, I have scoured the web looking and have come up with nothing.

Comment: There are leaks in the "cumulative" aspect of the updates.  I know for example that TypeScript will never be available unless you explicitly install Update 2 first.  Sounds like another case.

Comment: I recently had this problem in a completely different context. I wanted to create a Paradox Engine game project, and got the same error. I repaired my VS install and the Portable directory reappered in MSBuild\Microsoft. If you need the directory contents zipped, feel free to ask.

Comment: Have you had, at any point time, early releases of VS 13 or 15 installed on your machine?  I think they're still called CTP.  If so, you might need to nuke the OS and start from scratch with the released versions.  I've had CTP versions in the past irreparably corrupt the OS.

Comment: Yeah I have had early versions of VS 15. Thankfully, a complete uninstall and reinstall of all release versions of VS 13 and 15 worked for now.